# How do I wait till an animation is finished?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-mechanics

I am currently working on a Warfare 1917 like game. Right now I am trying to get the combat system working. I have made animations for a running and shooting soldier. It takes exactly 0.5 seconds till the animation lets the soldier shoot. 
I have taken out the animations, hud etc. because I put much effort in them and I don't want someone to steal them just now. :) It currently looks like this:

Obviously they are killing each other too fast. How can I let them wait till the animation is at the point where they can calculate if they die or not?
    This is my code. First it checks if two "soldiers" are in each others vicinity and then I calculate who of those two will die. `german.stop(true); britain.stop(true);`In the class where I handle the spawning and the animations of my soldiers I have a simple `if else` statement. Whenever `stop = true` then the soldier will stay at his current position and does his shooting animation. That this soldier continues to run after killing the other soldier is also a problem, but that's something for a later time.

```
ArrayList<britain> britainToRemove = new ArrayList<britain>();

ArrayList<germans> germansToRemove = new ArrayList<germans>();

    for (int i = german_array.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        germans german = german_array.get(i);
        for (int j = britain_array.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            britain britain = britain_array.get(j);
            if (german.getBounds().overlaps(britain.getBounds())) {
                //handle collision
                german.stop(true);
                britain.stop(true);
                int german_hit = random.nextInt(100) + 0;
                int britain_hit = random.nextInt(100) + 0;
                message = "Red: " + german_hit + "Blue: " + britain_hit;
                if (german_hit > britain_hit) {

                    britainToRemove.add(britain);

                } else {

                    germansToRemove.add(german);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    britain_array.removeAll(britainToRemove);
    german_array.removeAll(germansToRemove);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using LibGDX [`Animation`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html) class, you can use `isAnimationFinished()` method to check if animation has finished or not.

When you start your animation, you need to store starting time and subtract current time from it. Obviously, this needs to run as a separate loop with objects waiting for their animation to finish. You could use `britainToRemove` and `germansToRemove` for that. Iterate through these lists and remove elements from `britain_array` and `german_array` only when their animation finishes (don't forget to remove them from the list you are iterating through).

Note: My suggestion would make the two `*toRemove` lists state objects.

EDIT: If you care about performance, you should use `PriorityQueue` instead of iterating through the whole list.